# Oracle Identity Column

Tags: database, oracle

Is that the oracle table with identity column can only insert record one by one?
How can I insert multiple rows for the table with identity column?

My oracle version is:

Oracle Database 12c Standard Edition Release 12.1.0.2.0 - 64bit Production
PL/SQL Release 12.1.0.2.0 - Production
"CORE   12.1.0.2.0  Production"
TNS for 64-bit Windows: Version 12.1.0.2.0 - Production
NLSRTL Version 12.1.0.2.0 - Production

Here is my script to reproduce this problem

```
    CREATE TABLE T_BATCH_STATUS
    (
        ID INTEGER GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY NOT NULL
        , TARGET_DATE TIMESTAMP NOT NULL
        , JAVA_CLASS VARCHAR2(100) NOT NULL
        , STATUS VARCHAR2(35) NOT NULL
        , MSG VARCHAR2(1000)
        , FAIL_CNT NUMBER(3) default 0 NOT NULL
        , CREATE_USER VARCHAR2(35) NOT NULL
        , CREATE_DATE TIMESTAMP NOT NULL
        , UPDATE_USER VARCHAR2(35)
        , UPDATE_DATE TIMESTAMP
        , VERSION number(10) NOT NULL
        , CONSTRAINT PK_BATCH_STATUS PRIMARY KEY (ID)
        , CONSTRAINT U_BATCH_STATUS UNIQUE (TARGET_DATE, JAVA_CLASS)
    )
    ;

    insert into t_batch_status
    (
    TARGET_DATE
    , JAVA_CLASS
    , STATUS
    , FAIL_CNT
    , CREATE_USER
    , CREATE_DATE
    , VERSION
    )
    select to_date('2019.01.01', 'yyyy.MM.dd'), 'DownloadAndUnzip', 'NEW', 0, 'SYSTEM', sysdate, 0 from dual
    ;

    1 row inserted


insert into t_batch_status
(
TARGET_DATE
, JAVA_CLASS
, STATUS
, FAIL_CNT
, CREATE_USER
, CREATE_DATE
, VERSION
)
    select to_date('2019.02.14', 'yyyy.MM.dd'), 'DownloadAndUnzip', 'PENDING', 0,     'SYSTEM', sysdate, 0 from dual
    ;

1 row inserted.
```

But if I use union all to insert same 2 rows, the error occur:

```
truncate table t_batch_status;

insert into t_batch_status
(
TARGET_DATE
, JAVA_CLASS
, STATUS
, FAIL_CNT
, CREATE_USER
, CREATE_DATE
, VERSION
)
select to_date('2019.01.01', 'yyyy.MM.dd'), 'DownloadAndUnzip', 'NEW', 0, 'SYSTEM', sysdate, 0 from dual
union all select to_date('2019.02.14', 'yyyy.MM.dd'), 'DownloadAndUnzip', 'PENDING', 0, 'SYSTEM', sysdate, 0 from dual
;

Error report -
SQL Error: ORA-01400: cannot insert NULL into ("CYBERDB_DEV"."T_BATCH_STATUS"."ID")
01400. 00000 -  "cannot insert NULL into (%s)"
*Cause:    An attempt was made to insert NULL into previously listed objects.
*Action:   These objects cannot accept NULL values.
```

The error make me confuse, isn't that the ID column is auto generated?

After asked this question, I tried this and it works, so it must be an oracle bug:

```
insert into t_batch_status
(
TARGET_DATE
, JAVA_CLASS
, STATUS
, FAIL_CNT
, CREATE_USER
, CREATE_DATE
, VERSION
)
with tmp as (
select b.base + rownum target_date
from all_objects a
, (select to_date('2019.01.01', 'yyyy.MM.dd') base from dual) b
where rownum < 42
)
select target_date, 'DownloadAndUnzip' as JAVA_CLASS , 'NEW' as STATUS
, 0 as FAIL_CNT , 'SYSTEM' as CREATE_USER , sysdate as CREATE_DATE, 0  as VERSION 
from tmp
;

41 rows inserted.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It may be a bug in Oracle 12.1. When I tried it in Oracle 12.2, I receive *column ambiguously defined* error.

If I use proper aliases to all the columns in the first select query, it works fine

```
insert into t_batch_status
(
TARGET_DATE
, JAVA_CLASS
, STATUS
, FAIL_CNT
, CREATE_USER
, CREATE_DATE
, VERSION
)
select to_date('2019.01.01', 'yyyy.MM.dd') as TARGET_DATE , 
'DownloadAndUnzip' as JAVA_CLASS , 'NEW' as STATUS
, 0 as FAIL_CNT , 'SYSTEM' as CREATE_USER , sysdate as CREATE_DATE, 0  as VERSION 
   from dual
union all 
select to_date('2019.02.14', 'yyyy.MM.dd'), 'DownloadAndUnzip', 'PENDING',
 0, 'SYSTEM', sysdate, 0 from dual
;
```

Comment: Yes I confirmed it is a bug in oracle 12.1